# How to send functional object, created by bind to function/method?

Tags: c++, boost, std, bind

I have created a functional object for my randomization needs.

I just don't know how to send it to function/methods without templates.
With them its easy, just

```
template <typename T>
void FooTemplate (T rand)
{
   int b = rand(); // OK
}

void foo (... ?)
{
 int a = rand(); // how to send generator to function?
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
auto rand = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t>{20, 30}, std::default_random_engine{ std::random_device()() });
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void foo(std::function<int()> rand) {...}
```

`std::function<int()>` would wrap any callable, including that manufactured by `std::bind`

Comment: "*`std::function<int()>` would wrap any callable [...]*" - returning an `int`, that is :)

Comment: @Fureeish Returning a value of type implicitly convertible to `int`, if you want to be pedantic.

Comment: You are technically correct - the best kind of correct.